# Should I apply for a Spanish or Italian visa?

Tags: visas, italy, spain

I am Indian, travelling to Spain (Madrid 2 nights, Barcelona 3 nights) and then to Italy (Venice 2 nights. Florence 2 nights, Rome 3 nights). Which visa should I apply for?

Comment: Please see the answer to the above question. In your case, since you are spending equal time in each country, you should apply to the first country you are staying in.